# Gap in image - only on mobile - (how to make a responsive website)

Tags: html, css

[image]I'm trying to make a gap between the bottom of my div and my image disappear.

I tried reducing the bottom margin of the image, which worked...but only on pc, if you were to open my site on a mobile phone the gap would still be there

here is the class for the image and what I wrote for it to prevent the gap from happening but sadly this doesn't work on mobile:

.mountain {margin-bottom: -5px;}

It should've made there be no gap on both PC and mobile, so why is there one. Am I doing something wrong

btw if you guys could possibly open it on mobile (if you don't mind, literally everything changes), I also want to know how what I see on PC can be put at least almost the same thing on mobile

p.s. Here is the photo of the image on PC without changing the margin-bottom, should I add another photo but from mobile?

p.s.s here is the link to my little website . . . https://raynature.github.io/personal-site/

Comment: Can you show a link to the site? To add a screenshot, just click the little 'picture' icon in the editor. Also, using absolute pixel sizes doesn't translate as well to different screen sizes, as using a measure like `em`. Something like `-0.24em` or whatever might help.

Comment: sadly, that still doesn't change anything on mobile

Comment: What gap are you trying to get rid of? is it the light green thing? If so you have a margin on your profile-container element of 100px which is causing you to see that gap. **edit** also sidenote, margin-bottom with negative numbers does not function the same was as margin-left or margin-top.

Comment: no I'm trying get rid of the gap between the mountain and the light green "thing" (if you opened this on mobile, you would see a gap)

Comment: also see picture above

Comment: Well here's how it looks on my iMac.. how is it supposed to look? Show a picture of how you want it, and of how you don't want it thanks
https://i.imgur.com/ZSKAMiO.png

Comment: on my iPad "I'm Ray" is in the center of the page, and the mountain is almost gone off the bottom edge, I can only see the very top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images by default are inline elements. They follow the baseline of the text of the container they are in (even if there is no text). Add:

```
.mountain {
  vertical-align: bottom; 
}
```

to your image via your CSS.